# Escape Python to `json[]` for `COPY FROM` PostgreSQL insertion?

Tags: python, postgresql, escaping, psycopg2, postgresql-json

How do I correctly escape for `json[]` column insertion?

Currently I get this error, [[run script with more debugging](https://gist.github.com/SamuelMarks/fec744a620e2abd0257671aa6f2a96b4)]:

```
COPY "my_table" ("json_arr_col", "id") FROM STDIN WITH null as 'null' DELIMITER '|'
{'json_arr_col': '{"jj":null,"text":"bop"}\n'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "postgres_copy_from_array.py", line 98, in <module>
    psql_insert_copy(
  File "postgres_copy_from_array.py", line 38, in psql_insert_copy
    cur.copy_expert(sql=sql, file=s_buf)
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: malformed array literal: "{"jj":null,"text":"bop"}"
DETAIL:  Unexpected array element.
CONTEXT:  COPY my_table, line 1, column json_arr_col: "{"jj":null,"text":"bop"}"
```

How do I escape it so the `COPY FROM` succeeds? - Attempts:

- Call `dumps` twice, here:

```py
     elif isinstance(col, dict):
        return dumps(dumps(col, separators=(",", ":")))`
```

Gives:

```
COPY "my_table" ("json_arr_col", "id") FROM STDIN WITH null as 'null' DELIMITER '|'
{'json_arr_col': '"{\\"jj\\":null,\\"text\\":\\"bop\\"}"\n'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "postgres_copy_from_array.py", line 98, in <module>
    psql_insert_copy(
  File "postgres_copy_from_array.py", line 38, in psql_insert_copy
    cur.copy_expert(sql=sql, file=s_buf)
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: malformed array literal: ""{"jj":null,"text":"bop"}""
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
CONTEXT:  COPY my_table, line 1, column json_arr_col: ""{"jj":null,"text":"bop"}""
```

---

```python
from io import StringIO
from json import dumps

import psycopg2.sql


def psql_insert_copy(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        s_buf = StringIO()
        s_buf.write(
            "\n".join(
                map(lambda l: "|".join(map(str, map(parse_col, l))), data_iter)
            )
        )
        s_buf.seek(0)

        sql = "COPY {} ({}) FROM STDIN WITH null as 'null' DELIMITER '|'".format(
            psycopg2.sql.Identifier(
                *(table.schema, table.name) if table.schema else (table.name,)
            ).as_string(cur),
            psycopg2.sql.SQL(", ")
            .join(
                map(
                    psycopg2.sql.Identifier,
                    keys[1:] if keys and keys[0] == "index" else keys,
                )
            )
            .as_string(cur),
        )
        cur.copy_expert(sql=sql, file=s_buf)
```

My helper function:

```python
from functools import partial
from json import dumps
import numpy as np

def parse_col(col):
    if isinstance(col, np.ndarray):
        return parse_col(col.tolist()) if col.size > 0 else "null"
    elif isinstance(col, bool):
        return int(col)
    elif isinstance(col, bytes):
        return parse_col(col.decode("utf8"))
    elif isinstance(col, (complex, int)):
        return col
    elif isinstance(col, float):
        return int(col) if col.is_integer() else col
    elif col in (None, "{}", "[]") or not col:
        return "null"
    elif isinstance(col, str):
        return {"True": 1, "False": 0}.get(col, col)
    elif isinstance(col, (list, tuple, set, frozenset)):
        return "{{{0}{1}}}".format(
            ",".join(map(partial(dumps, separators=(",", ":")),
                         map(parse_col, col))),
            "," if len(col) == 1 else "",
        )
    elif isinstance(col, dict):
        return dumps(col, separators=(",", ":"))
    elif isinstance(col, datetime):
        return col.isoformat()
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(type(col))
```

Usage:

```python
from itertools import repeat
from collections import namedtuple

import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    "dbname=test_user_db user=test_user"
)
conn.cursor().execute(
    "CREATE TABLE my_table ("
    "  json_arr_col json[],"
    "  id integer generated by default as identity primary key"
    ");"
)

psql_insert_copy(
    conn=conn,
    keys=("json_arr_col", "id"),
    data_iter=repeat(({"jj": None, "text": "bop"},), 5),
    table=namedtuple("_", ("name", "schema"))("my_table", None),
)
```

Comment: 1) Use proper [parameter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) and [dynamic sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html). Use the built in [JSON adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json).

Comment: *You* don't. You start with a data structure, and let the `json` and/or `psycopg2` modules do any encoding. Under no circumstances should you be using any string-formatting operations to do this yourself.

Comment: Also why `JSON[]`? That would be a Postgres array of JSON items. You would be essentially mixing types and causing yourself headaches. Just use `JSON ` or `JSONB` type.

Comment: Defining a column as an array of json `json[`]` almost never makes sense. It's better to use `jsonb` (or at least `json`)  and store an JSON array.

Comment: @chepner & adrian-klaver Ok I'm happy not to use my custom parse/emit code. What do I use instead, keeping in mind I am using this method https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert

Answer (score 0):

A short simple example:

```
cat js_vals.json 
[{"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}]
[{"dog": "ranger", "cat": "cassie", "fish": "trout"}]


import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql

con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", host='localhost', user='postgres')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE my_table (
    json_arr_col jsonb,
    id integer generated by default as identity primary key)""")
con.commit()

# sql.Identifier("public", "my_table") becomes "public"."my_table".
sql = sql.SQL("COPY {} ({}) FROM STDIN").format(sql.Identifier("public", "my_table"), sql.Identifier("json_arr_col"))

with open("js_vals.json", "r") as js_file:
    cur.copy_expert(sql, js_file)
con.commit()

cur.execute("select * from my_table")
cur.fetchall()
[([{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}], 1),
 ([{'cat': 'cassie', 'dog': 'ranger', 'fish': 'trout'}], 2)]
```

**UPDATE**. Add `varchar` column. Did not add `json[]` for two reasons:

1. I don't see the point in using a Postgres `array` type to hold  `JSON` values when the `json` and `jsonb` types are available.
2. It would probably require writing an adapter to get `psycopg2` copy* to recognize that `json(b)[]` is desired.

```
cat js_vals.csv 
test|[{"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}]
test2|[{"dog": "ranger", "cat": "cassie", "fish": "trout"}]


cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table")
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE my_table (
    varchar_col varchar,
    json_arr_col jsonb,
    id integer generated by default as identity primary key)""")
con.commit()

sql = sql.SQL("COPY {} ({},{}) FROM STDIN  DELIMITER '|'").format(sql.Identifier("public", "my_table"), sql.Identifier("varchar_col"),  sql.Identifier("json_arr_col"))

with open("js_vals.csv", newline='') as csv_file:
    cur.copy_expert(sql, csv_file)
con.commit()

cur.execute("select * from my_table")

cur.fetchall()

[('test', [{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}], 1),
 ('test2', [{'cat': 'cassie', 'dog': 'ranger', 'fish': 'trout'}], 2)]
```

Comment: Wait, so it supports normal JSON now? - I was making `[{"foo":5}]` into `{"{\"foo\":5}",}` as that seems to be what PostgreSQL requires. You might want to complicate your example to insert 3 columns, say a `json`, a `json[]`, and a `VARCHAR(20)`. That will require escaping each column's data in turn.

Comment: Postgres does not require that: `select '[{"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}]'::jsonb; [{"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}]`

Comment: Ok I'm using `psycopg2.sql.SQL(", ").join` and `psycopg2.sql.Identifier` everywhere now, and using the `|` delimited content. But still getting the `psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: malformed array literal` on insertions into `json[]`

Comment: I updated my question to include a new attempt